# Is it possible to create an optimal real time image processing project using JavaScript with Arduino?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, arduino, real-time

I want to use a camera to detect objects while driving and match them to patterns using AI. I prefer JavaScript - e.g. Johnny-Five for Arduino and p5.js for image processing. Does it make a sense to use these technologies? I think that it is possible but I don't know if it has a sense considering efficiency.

Comment: well that depends what MCU , camera connection resolution/bandwith and DIP/CV operations vs. FPS you need/want to use. Most people forgetting that Arduino is just a framework not HW and by using it you are not fully embracing used HW architecture.  So you need to be more specific add things like: MCU type (or at least properties like MIPS/MHz) implementation characteristics MCU clock, Memory size and speed, free timeslot for operation (camera can take a lot of time from your frame just to interconnect and receive data from it). Also add sample images from your camera that you want to inspect.

Comment: Another option is go to signal procesing SO site and look for questions similar to your task how they do it. Usually DSP is used for such things but I think the faster Atmel MCUs like AT32UC3 and newer can handle such if the DIP/CV is not too much ... anyway I would use C++ (GCC) from Atmel Studio 2.7 to be sure you got all the MCU power at your disposal not sure how JavaScript works (if it is emulated/interpreted/compiled which affects performance a lot)